# Многие ко многим в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть 3 таблицы:

ActionType: Action_id,Name

Premission:Permission_id,Name

ActionTypePermission:Action_id,Permission_id,DateDel

При подходе DataBase first студия сгенерила мне 2 класса.
Вопрос:

1) Я как нибудь могу получить доступ к данным сущности UserPermission?

2) Я могу получить доступ к DateDel и выбрать, например, Login, где Datedel== null ?

3) Как я могу заставить сгенерить мне UserPermission помимо введения другого ключевого атрибута UserPermission_id?

Сами классы:

```
public partial class ActionType
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ActionType()
    {
        this.Queues = new HashSet<Queue>();
        this.UserChangeHistories = new HashSet<UserChangeHistory>();
        this.Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }

    public int Action_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Queue> Queues { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserChangeHistory> UserChangeHistories { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
public partial class Permission
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Permission()
    {
        this.UserPermissions = new HashSet<UserPermission>();
        this.ActionTypes = new HashSet<ActionType>();
    }

    public int Permission_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ActionType> ActionTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: А где сгенеренные классы?

Comment: @Monk, я дополнил.

Comment: а Вы пробовали обращаться к навигационным свойствам: `Permissions`, на сколько я могу судить в нем должны быть разрешения для типа действия

Comment: Да, но datedel, я там не нашел...

Comment: не забывайте ставить символ `@`+Ник того кому пишите, что бы пришла нотификация. что то я не вижу свойства `datadel` в вашем классе `Permission`(по крайней мере в той части которую Вы привели)

Comment: @Bald, странно, я обновил модель из БД. Может быть при многие ко многим не генерятся другие поля, кроме поле для связи?

Comment: Собственно говоря, а где же класс **ActionTypePermission**?

Comment: нет, другие поля тоже должны генериться. Вы не первый кто сталкивается с проблемой обновления при использовании *database fisrt*. обновите модель и думаю все у Вас заработает

Comment: @Bald, я делаю Update from DataBase. Можно как-то по другому?

Comment: @DenisBubnov а его сообственно быть и не должно, на основании конструктора Entiti Framework создает связующую таблицу при подходе code first

Comment: где то я читал, что подобную проблему удалось решить *пересоздав модель*, т.е. из проекта была удалена существующая модель и добавлена заново, не забудьте на всякий случай сделать backup :)

Comment: @Bald, а что в итоге должно случится? Из-за того, что появится колонка DateDel должен сгенерироваться класс ActionTypePermission?

Comment: вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34781070/5610621) говорят что можно удалить таблицу из `edmx` файла и после этого сделать `update from database`. после того как Вы обновите модель с свойстве `Permissions` будет существовать необходимое Вам свойство

Comment: @Bald, действительно сгенерировался отдельный класс под сущность.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37945/discussion-between-bald-and-iluxa1810).